# Dynamic controls disappear after postback

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, postback, pageload

I have a whole lot of controls to be created dynamically. Where is the best place to run the code for that?

I have been running the CreateControls function (to create all controls) at Page_Load.

Now the problem is, when I uncheck/uncheck one particular dynamic checkbox control (autopostback = true), the checkbox is always set to "true" because the CreateControls function runs again at Page_Load on postback.

If I put the CreateControls function within the (!IsPostBack) of Page_Load, when I click on the dynamic checkbox control, all controls disappear.

I have been looking at this for days, any ideas appreciated!

**EDIT**: The CreateControls function binds all the controls to a Panel.

Comment: Why are you adding those controls dynamically? persisting those is a PITA; try to reassess your logic and come up with some other way of solving your problem.

Comment: Click on the "Related" links to the right of your question, you might find help there.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys - I need to create those controls dynamically for a reason - there are 30 controls that needed to be created based data from a back-end SQL table.

Comment: what if you drop them all on the page, and toggle the visibility based on the date from the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling your CreateControls method in `Page_Init` method instead of `Page_Load`... the `Init` event fires before the form values are bound to the controls, so your default values will be overwritten with the correct data.

Comment: I am still a bit confused regarding IsPostBack. Do I need to put the CreateControl within if(!IsPostBack)?

Comment: No, you need to bind on postbacks as well.

Comment: thanks. 
Another question - at the end of my CreateControl() I have codes to add all of the controls to a Panel (i.e. Panel1.Controls.Add(chkbox))

Now using PreInit, I get an error on these codes "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Where do I put these codes now? Thanks!

Comment: Page_Init seems to work better... I've always used it, but saw the MSDN article and assumed PreInit was better.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks...
I've ran into another problem: so CreateControl() dynamically creates controls like Table tb = new Table(). Then I assign them an ID like e.g. tb.ID = "table" + j.ToString() based on a loop. Now that I've made the changes to run in Page_init, it is giving me errors "Multiple controls with the same ID "table0" where found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: Dont worry about my previous comment!!

Comment: Are you executing `CreateControls` twice now?

Comment: It's working now - I just forgot to take off my CreateControl from Page_Load.
Thank you SOO much Glen!! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes Igor, you are right, I made a mistake. CreateControl should only be in Page_init only!

Comment: Can I ask another related question here?: On every postback, the screen jumps back to the top. Normally with this problem, I create an ScriptManager/UpdatePanel in the .aspx page for each control. But since this is all done dynamically, is there a way around this?

Comment: An UpdatePanel should probably work in this scenario as well.  Otherwise, you could try using the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack Page directive, but I think it's a little quirky at times.

Comment: I have something like 25+ dynamic controls within my Panel. So I put the <UpdatePanel><ContentTemplate> around my <asp:Panel>
that is the correct approach right? I keep getting some microsoftAjax.js/JSScript runtime error>:Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.